# Query Wikipedia: retrieve links from a category page

Tags: mysql, mediawiki, categories, wikipedia

I am trying to query all the page links of a category page in Wikipedia. 
It was easy to do it with templates but I am having problems with categories.

I generally log into Wikipedia by ssh at ...@tools-login.wmflabs.org
and access their mysql database.

For example, for the templates I generally do :

```
SELECT pl.pl_title
FROM page p
JOIN pagelinks pl on p.page_id=pl.pl_from
WHERE p.page_title='Aviation_accidents_and_incidents_in_2014' AND
      p.page_namespace=10 AND
      pl.pl_namespace=0;
```

this query easily gives me all the page links of this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Aviation_accidents_and_incidents_in_2014

If I want to do the same with the category page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Aviation_accidents_and_incidents_in_2004:

```
SELECT pl.pl_title
FROM page p
JOIN pagelinks pl on p.page_id=pl.pl_from
WHERE p.page_title='Aviation_accidents_and_incidents_in_2014' AND
      p.page_namespace=14 AND
      pl.pl_namespace=0;
```

It returns nothing.

I have tried other combinations but still can't get it (zero results again).

```
SELECT pl.pl_title
FROM category c
JOIN pagelinks pl on c.cat_id=pl.pl_from
WHERE c.cat_title='Aviation_accidents_and_incidents_in_2014' AND
      pl.pl_namespace=0;
```

Do you happen to have an example of this?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: For example, what I would expect to obtain among the results, is a link to the flight Algerian Air Force C-130 crash and the others listed there

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use MediaWiki's [categorylinks table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Categorylinks_table):

```
SELECT p.page_title
FROM categorylinks AS cl
JOIN page AS p ON p.page_id=cl.cl_from
WHERE cl.cl_to='Aviation_accidents_and_incidents_in_2014';
```

See the results [here](http://quarry.wmflabs.org/query/7839).

Comment: Yes, you are right! I got confused with the order of links. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this in python?